# BigQuery: How to enable standard SQL in C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, google-bigquery

I've been trying to follow the documentation https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql but haven't been able to find the useLegacySql field in Job.Configuration. I'm using Bigquery.v2.1.9.2.2280.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any changes in the API calls, just trying sending your Standard SQL queries with "#StandardSQL" as the first line:

```
#StandardSQL
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `ghtorrent-bq.ght.project_languages`
```

Comment: Thanks @Felipe Hoffa, this works and doesn't require changing the jobs configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally used that API before, but are you looking at the reference for [`JobConfigurationQuery`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Bigquery_1_1v2_1_1Data_1_1JobConfigurationQuery.html)? It has a [`UseLegacySql`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Bigquery_1_1v2_1_1Data_1_1JobConfigurationQuery.html#ac7f41fbdd793c8c6f91da392132d6e0e) attribute.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using API - you can enable standard SQL using the following methods:

- Setting the useLegacySql property of jobs.query to false.
  To learn more, see the [useLegacySql](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query#useLegacySql) section of the Jobs: query topic.
- Using jobs.insert method and setting configuration.query.useLegacySql to false.
  To learn more, see the [configuration.query.useLegacySql](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query.useLegacySql) section of the Jobs topic.

Comment: Thanks @MikhailBerlyant, I was using an old dll from BigQuery which didn't have the useLegacySql field, and I was reluctant to update it because that may break other parts of our code. The solution Felipe Hoffa gave seems to be a better choice.